# prevent upgrading of a dependency for just the module that uses it

Tags: linux, yum, dependencies

I am working with Amazon Linux 2013.09. I have a module that requires dependency perl( module_compat_5.10.0). When I try and update using yum, the package manager tries to upgrade it as well and breaks the dependency or stops updating most of the OS.

Is there a way I could keep the dependency for just my module and upgrade it for the rest of the OS ? If I was still Installing this module on a newer OS would it be possible to install this dependency and use it just for this module with out downgrading it for the rest of the OS ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `exclude=<rpm>` in `/etc/yum.conf`?

Comment: yea , the update still keeps failing as all other components would need the package to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
yum versionlock <package-name>
```

http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq

Comment: Thanks for your response, I could lock the dependency but since other parts of the OS require the same package to be updated to work. yum update just fails.